# TypeScript question regarding "extends" for interfaces

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write a Filter-Type for a query system. When trying to write a `getItem(id)` method I stumbled upon this and I do not know why Typescript does not permit this.

Inside I had the function typed as `<Type extends BaseType>` which would not allow me to run the query with the `id` property, regardless of the fact that `Type` will extend `BaseType` and have the `id` property.

The `f<T>` part will throw this error:

```
Argument of type '{ a: { eq: "123"; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<TypePropertyFilter<T>>'.ts(2345)
```

```
/**
 * This setup should support "queries" like:
 * { id: { eq: "abc"}, someVal: { lt: 5 }}
 */

export type FilterName = 'eq' // | 'lt' | 'gt // etc...

export type FilterRecord<Type> = Record<FilterName, Type | Type[]>

export type TypePropertyFilter<Type extends {}> = {
  [P in keyof Type]: Partial<FilterRecord<Type[P]>>
}

export type Filter<Type> = Partial<TypePropertyFilter<Type>>



interface BaseType { a: string, b: number }

interface TestType extends BaseType {
  test: boolean
}

const t: TestType = { id: "123", test: "pitr"} as any

const f = <T>(f: Filter<T>) => null

const r = <T extends BaseType>() => {

  f<TestType>({
    a: {eq: "123"}, // correct (fails with other type)
    b: { eq: 4555 }, // correct (fails with other type)
    test: { eq: true } // correct (fails with other type)
  })
  f<BaseType>({
    a: {eq: "123"}, // correct (fails with other type)
    b: { eq: 4555 }, // correct (fails with other type)
    // test: { eq: true } // correctly fails, not of BaseType
  })
  f<T>({
    a: {eq: "123"}, // fails but should succeed, T extends BaseType and should at least support all that f<NodeType> does
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the `T` in `T extends BaseType` could be a type such as

```
{
  a: "foo" | "bar";
  b: number;
}
```

and in that case your filter `{ a: {eq: "123"} }` would not be safe

Comment: You might be correct with this. Had not thought about the Type actually being able to limit the BaseType. Do you have any Idea how I can enforce the type of a to be a string, and only be a string, not "restrictable"?